# Selecting random folders using Keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, selection

What I wish to do while selecting.

[image]

Clicking by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

---

Trying to do it with keyboard.

[image]

Using the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and arrow keys

---

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to skip a folder and pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select the required one.

[image]

But the folder in between gets selected as well.

---

So how do I use only keyboard to perform what I did with the mouse and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple actually.

You hold the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key, then you use the arrow keys to move around as you normally would. While still holding the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key, you can add/remove a file from the selection by pressing <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

You release <kbd>CTRL</kbd> once you are satisfied with your selection.