# Select multiple files individually in explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

To my knowledge, I know 3 ways of selecting files in explorer.

Assume a folder with 10 files. Now,

- I can select one individual file by single-clicking it.
- I can also drag the cursor using mouse to select files in a range such as 1st to 3rd.
- To select all I can hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

But when I will need to select 1st, 3rd and 5th then how would I select those files?

I am currently in windows 10 Pro x64 build 2004 if it matters. I have also Windows 7 x64 Ultimate, and I will be glad if the way works in there too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/q/1548259

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just you can hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and select the files.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> lets you add files to selection one by one.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> selects a range of files. Click any file, then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then click another file. These two files and all files between them will be selected.

These two can be combined: you can select files using <kbd>Shift</kbd> (or any other method like dragging or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), then add more with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> also lets you unselect files.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on "Use check boxes to select items" in folder options in Explorer. Then just click the checkbox next to the 1st, 3rd, and 5th files. No additional keypresses necessary after that.